How does the wash sale rule apply to options with different expiration dates?
There is some debate among tax experts regarding whether options with different strike prices or expiration dates are considered substantially identical. Some argue that they are not, while others maintain that they are, especially if they pertain to the same underlying stock.
How does the wash sale rule apply to options with different expiration dates?
